# call Button event from java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET C# Website
I have a JavaScript function. In this function, I need to fire a **button event**.
Any suggestions/link?

***EDIT***

I have a validation function in javascript that i validate on clicking this button. I have a situation, like when i click the button then i need the validation but when I am performing the click(through  `$("#ID").trigger("click");`) then it is not required. Any suggestion?

Comment: How was the event attached to the button?

Comment: refer this link http://aspalliance.com/1701_Using_JavaScript_Effectively_in_ASPNET_20__Part_1.all

Comment: How did you defined a button ? Is it html or asp.net component ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#mybutton").trigger("click");  // just fires click event on the button
$("#mybutton").click();           // simulates button click
```

Comment: ...assuming the OP is using jQuery.

Comment: I have a validation function in javascript that i validate on clicking this button. I have a situation, like when i click the button then i need the validation but when I performing the click like as suggested by you in above code. then it is not required. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't tag as jQuery, I'll assume you're not using it.

If you're setting the event like this:

```
var someButton = document.getElementById("yourButtonId");
someButton.addEventListener('click', clickEvent);
```

Then you can raise the click event later like this:

```
clickEvent();
```

This also works for me, but I'm not sure how cross-browser safe it is:

```
var button = document.getElementById("yourButtonId");
button.click();
```